# react-bootstrap collapsable table row

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi I know how to use the collapsable mixin, I succeed to make a  collapsable but can't make a whole  collapsable.

Really hard to do , any clue how to do that ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you edit the question to include what you have already tried? A link to a jsfiddle for example?

Comment: try hiding the row using html tags and `getElementById`.